# When to use multi threading vs multi processsing

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing

I would like to see some spot on examples. I know the differences between them (same PID, same virtual address for threads etc.).

---

For instance,  does using the same address limit the usages or power of threads? or on the contrary, does it make multi processing more powerful but less efficient?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If your threads share data, and you want to avoid IPC, place them in the same process. Otherwise, different processes become an option.

Comment: its not clear to me when to choose processes over threads and want to see some examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main advantage of threads is that **if** they need to share data, there is nothing to do except a correct synchronisation (since adresse space is shared between them).

On the contrary, **if** some processes need to share data, a communication means must be explicitly set up (shared memory segment, pipe, local socket...) and its use generally implies copying the data (ie, address_space_1 --> shared segment --> address_space_2,
or even address_space_1 --[pipe]--> kernel memory --[pipe]--> address_space_2).
These copies could be a performance bottleneck (depending on applicative context).

But an advantage of processes over threads is that if one process is killed, the others can go on working (assuming that the communication protocol between them is robust enough).

It might have been said a long time ago that thread scheduling could be more efficient than process scheduling but it is not true any more (it was probably related to user-space threads, not kernel threads).